# encounter "Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, value = lmer(f, data = df)) : no such index at level 1

Tags: r

I ran this code before and it worked. However, now it is not working anymore.

```
FCs<-list(colnames(df[3:23]))#a list of var names


md<-list()

for (i in FCs){ 
  f <- formula(paste(i,"~ Predictor +(age|ID)"))
  md[[i]] <- lmer(f, data=df)#error happens when running this line}
```

I've searched around and tried using `length`, `seq_along`, and used `lapply`, but nothing solved the problem.
It seems that the first step of the loop reads all the content in the list, but then stopped.

I've also seen some posts say it could be a bug related to updating of the packages or R/RStudio.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: `list(colnames(df[3:23]))` is *one* item containing all the names. Do you want just `colnames(df[3:23])` which will be 21 items?

Comment: @thelatemail oo it worked! thank you! weirdly this line worked before....